# What are those objects of the top of this building called?

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete

[image]

Does anyone know what these things on the ceiling of this building are called?

I am referring to those objects with semicircle shape that act as a ceiling on the 
 top of the building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Kuwait National assembly building designed by Jorn Utzon, Danish architect. In your image the building is under construction.

The objects are permanent formwork for roof concrete slab. They create the grooves on top that is going to be populated with reinforcement and mold the stem of T-beam Roof slab.

At the same time, they are nicely arched on the bottom and will play as the dramatic voluted ceiling of the building.

He utilizes this type of architectural feature in many of his designs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just one more question. Why does he add the same objects between the ground floor and second floor. Is he trying to add more height to the building?

Comment: @user3911153, yes and it could be that he uses their end half circles as an atrium skylight. It is a famous building with many photos available, I was not sure about copyright, otherwise, I would have posted some.